# How to put a folder on PATH with Python?

Tags: python, dll, path, os.path

Given  I have a folder 'foo' with some .dll files which needs to be on PATH at runtime of my python script 'setup.py'
Is it possible to put code inside my `setup.py` script that will put 'foo' folder on `PATH` before executing the reset of the code which requires the `.dll` files to run?

So far I have tried this:

```
import sys
import os
foo = os.path.abspath('dependencies/foo')
if sys.path[1]!= foo:
    print('Adding foo to PATH:')
    sys.path.insert(1, foo)
    print sys.path
else:
    print('foo is already on PATH!')

import lib_which_requires_dll_from_foo
...
```

but it has no effect, although `sys.path` shows that 'foo' is on `PATH` - or am I mistaken and it's not that PATH which it should be on.

My setup.py script works if I put 'foo' on `PATH` with `set PATH=C:\my_path_to\foo;%PATH%)`

Comment: `sys.path` is used to find python modules. Why do you expect it to affect dll loading?

Comment: Does your script work if you put the .dll files into the current directory that you launch the script from? I don't use Windows, but IIRC, .dll files generally live in system32.

Comment: @spectras I am relative new to python ... obviously my expection was wrong :(

If `sys.path` is the wrong method which one should I use instead?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, it work. So what does that mean? Would it be ok to just add the files to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: No, the shell's `PYTHONPATH` and Python's `sys.path` are used to find _Python_ files. Those `.dll` files should go somewhere that your OS will look when it's trying to find a DLL, so (as I said before) either the current directory or WINDOWS/system32. FWIW, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26878137/4014959) is some Python code I wrote a couple of years ago that uses an external library, it works on Windows and on Linux.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the link. If I understand the code right it requires to import `ctypes` and then use `cdll.LibraryLoader`? 'Name' parameter of LibraryLoader can bee a folder name, too or must it be a single .dll? In my 'foo' folder I have 6 .dll and 3 .lib files.

Comment: I don't think you can give a pathname to `cdll.LibraryLoader`; at least, all the examples in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries) just give the base name of the library.

Comment: I solved my problem with `os.environ['PATH']`. Here's the code:
`import sys
import os
foo = os.path.abspath('dependencies/foo')
if os.environ['PATH'].find(foo):
    print('Adding foo to PATH:')
    os.environ['PATH'] = foo + ";" + os.environ['PATH']
    print('Done!')
    print os.environ['PATH']
else:
    print('foo is already on PATH!')`

But just wonder why it is `if os.environ ...` instead of as I expected `if not os.environ ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
FOO = os.path.abspath('path_to_my/FOO')
os.environ['PATH'] = FOO + ";" + os.environ['PATH']
```

I removed the if condition because `PATH` is altered temporary only - not permanently, thus there is no need to check it first.

**NOTE:** that will propably work on Windows only.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40239544/2) to the question [How to put a folder on PATH with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239544/how-to-put-a-folder-on-path-with-python) by the OP [Wlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4445175/wlad) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>