# Why is printf() giving a strange output in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I tried to use the C-function `printf()` in the python command line on Linux. To make that work, I imported `ctypes`. My problem is: If I create an object of `CDLL` to use the `printf()`-function in a loop, I get a really weird output:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> for i in range(10):
...     libc.printf("%d", i)
...
01
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
>>>
```

However, when I call this loop inside a function, it works as expected:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> def pr():
...     for i in range(10):
...         libc.printf("%d", i)
...     libc.printf("\n")
...
>>> pr()
0123456789
>>>
```

I can't guess what causes this behavior ...
I'm using Python 2.7.6 on Linux if it matters.

**EDIT:**

Python version / operating system has no influence to this. See PM 2Ring's answer below for details. On Windows you only have to change the initialization of `libc` to `libc = ctypes.CDLL("msvcrt.dll")` where `.dll` is optional. Another way to get the correct output than calling a function would be storing the return value of `printf()` in a variable:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")  # "mscvrt.dll" on windows
>>> for i in range(10):
...     r = libc.printf("%d", i)
...
0123456789>>>
```

I still prefer the function because you can add a concluding linebreak easier.

Comment: Actually an easier way to suppress output is to just add a semicolon to the end: `libc.printf("%d", i);`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Those extra `'1'`s at the end of each number are the return value from `printf`, which returns the number of chars that it prints. The return value of a function called in the interactive interpreter is automatically printed (unless it's `None`).

In fact, the interactive interpreter prints any non-`None` expression that isn't assigned. And of course it adds a newline to those expressions, which explains why the output in your first code block is on separate lines.

Your `pr` function doesn't have a return statement, so it returns `None`, and thus no extra stuff gets printed.

Comment: And it doesn't get printed in the function, because the function code isn't interactive anymore?

Comment: @Aemyl Basically. You're calling `pr` in the interactive context, so its return value gets printed by the interpreter, but any functions that `pr` calls work normally, otherwise the terminal would get filled with unwanted rubbish. :)

Comment: ok, so it doesn't matter which python version / operating system I use?

Comment: @Aemyl No, that's standard on all versions of the standard (CPython) interpreter and on all OSes. There _are_ other Python interpreters / IDEs, but by default they also print the value of non-`None` expressions when running in interactive mode (AFAIK), although they may also print additional information.

Comment: Same thing without the printf call: `for i in range(10): 1`

Comment: Note: `ipython` (a _very_ common alternative interactive interpreter that wraps the CPython interpreter, as one of a bazillion features) is smarter, and doesn't output the result of unassigned expressions in a block. It only outputs for individual expressions that aren't assigned.

Comment: Hi, Hope you are doing well there. I have couple of questions about python, can we talk over messenger or something? that would be great if we could)))

Comment: @SardorIslomov Hi. You should visit the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Answer (score 5):

While PM 2Ring has answered the question quite well, I think it's worth pointing out that printf's behaviour, or something very close, is available as a python built-in, so it's really quite strange that you'd be using the C library version, unless you're using it to learn how to use `ctypes`, in which case carry on.

But on the other hand, it's strange to want to use `ctypes` when you haven't used enough python to know how the REPL works... at the risk of sounding arrogant, as someone with 10 years of python experience, I've never actually had to use `ctypes` yet.

There are two built-in options for string formatting in python:

```
print("%d" % (i,))
```

which is the old style, and very similar to printf, and

```
print("{:d}".format(i))
```

which is new to python 3, and is somewhat more powerful. There are [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) addressing the differences on this site. Both of the above lines will output identically to `libc.printf("%d\n", i)`. It's also possible to [print without the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space).

The CPython implementation of "%" string formatting actually uses sprintf [under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L2568).

Comment: I agree that there's virtually no point in using C's `printf` in Python, apart from as a learning exercise in using `ctypes`.  I guess the fact that it returns the number of characters printed _could_ be handy, but it'd be saner to just use normal Python string formatting & get the `len` of the result before printing. FWIW, the `format` function & method have bee back-ported to Python 2.6 & 2.7. And Python 3 introduces yet another way to format strings: [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498) aka f-strings.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't used `ctypes` much, either, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26878137/4014959) is a program I wrote that uses it to access the OpenSSL crypto library in order to implement a resumable SHA256 hash function.