# Is there a way to safely store the internal state of an SHA256 hash

Tags: python, hashlib

I'm looking for a way to store the internal state of an sha256 hash in python and then bring it back later so that I can continue hashing the stream of content where the code left off previously.

I suppose this might be possible via pickle but that raises a security risk because I want to store the state externally.

Is there any way to get at the internal bits/bytes of a `hashlib.sha256()` and then later create a new one from those same internal bytes.  IE: this would work as if the later created one was made via the `copy()` method on the first.

### A little more context

I'm uploading chunks of data to AWS S3 which will ultimately form a multipart upload.  They're sent in a strict order and will initially be uploaded as S3 objects in their own right.  When all have been uploaded they'll then be rolled into one object using [upload_part_copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_part_copy).  At the end of the process I want to know the final SHA256 hash of the combined object.

I won't know the full file content until all parts are uploaded, so there's no way to know the SHA256 hash ahead of time.  There's a requirement to make this process resumable.  What I DON'T want to do is download 500GB of content just to re-compute the hashes.

My idea is that I could maintain a `hashlib.sha256()` object while I'm uploading then I might be able to extract the internal state of the hash object each time I upload a chunk of data and attach that as metadata to the chunk.  If I need to resume then all I need to do is fetch the metadata on the last chunk and restore the hash object.

Comment: duplicate of [Persisting hashlib state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130892/persisting-hashlib-state)

Answer (score 1):

## Rehash: Resumable Hashlib

https://github.com/kislyuk/rehash

> Rehash is a resumable interface to the OpenSSL-based hashers (message
> digest objects) in the CPython hashlib standard library. Rehash
> provides hashers that can be pickled, persisted and reconstituted from
> their repr(), and otherwise serialized. The rest of the Rehash API is
> identical to hashlib.
>
> Rehash hashers can be used to checkpoint and restore progress when
> hashing large byte streams:
>
> ```
> import pickle, rehash
> hasher = rehash.sha256(b"foo")
> state = pickle.dumps(hasher)
>
> hasher2 = pickle.loads(state)
> hasher2.update(b"bar")
>
> assert hasher2.hexdigest() == rehash.sha256(b"foobar").hexdigest()
> ```

##### `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`

```py
import rehash
hasher = rehash.sha256(b"foo")
state = hasher.__getstate__()

hasher2 = rehash.sha256()
hasher2.__setstate__(state)
hasher2.update(b"bar")
```

Comment: Hmmm pickle is often a concern where it is being stored externally.  I'll take a look to see if this is still usable though.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I'm not sure if this addresses your concern but it is also can be reconstituted from its repr().

Comment: @PhilipCouling You could also sign the pickle dump with an HMAC stored in a separate file. So that the pickle file can be checked for unauthorized changes before loading it.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Did you find an issue around your concern with pickle?

Comment: I don't think rehash is going to be quite right fit for what I want.  However I note it does not appear to implement sha256, and instead uses python's one. So somewhere in its source code will be the direct answer to my question of how to extract the internal state.

Comment: @PhilipCouling rehash uses ctypes to implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`. Updated answer with an example.